# run command where specific user login

Tags: command-line

I have made a script that I want to run only where the user kyle logs in. I don't want it to be run on all users like a start-up app. I only want it to run when the user kyle logs in

Comment: Which DE (Desktop Environment) is being used?

Answer (score 0):

To setup tasks to run on login, use `gnome-session-properties`. This means you can add programs to run when you login to the user account on your machine.
[image]

You can configure it like this - just add the command you want to run in the command box:
[image: config]

Very long answer on that [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/48327/178596)

Comment: Nice answer. I advise you use the full path to executables and files ;)